# Show a subset of points on an AndroidPlot line chart

Tags: android, charts, linechart, panning, androidplot

I've been working with `Androidplot` library for generating line plots and be able to do zoom and pan, so I'm using a modified version of `XYPlotZoomPan` class.

My current chart is showing some values per day, in a range of dates, so if I'm showing 7 days the domain axis is readable but if I'm trying to show 30 days it turns into a mess.

My goal is to show 7 days and have the option of scrolling through the rest of the chart that is not shown.

The only function that handles boundaries is `setDomainBoundaries`, currently I've tried this:

```
  setDomainBoundaries(min, max, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
```

But it lets me show values inside this range and I'm loosing the ability for panning through the rest of the days.

Does someone have an a idea how I can do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own domain value format with `myplot.setDomainValueFormat(Format f)`. From here you can create your own formatter.

Another option you can look at is setDomainStep, a good example of that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768100/android-plot-fixed-values-on-x-angle)

Comment: @emanzanomarcos I have the same problem as you. How did this suggestion help? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with panning.

Comment: I needed to reduce the number of points on domain axis so with setDomainStep you can do it, but I can't remember how I could scroll horizontally through the chart. 
Sorry but I've lost the code of that project.
I think I disabled vertical zoom and set a fixed horizontal zoom value programatically.